# How do I shorten file path output to text files in batch files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, dir

```
@echo off
REM - Check to see if there are any non-school related files on the system (mp3, jpg, png, exe)
REM - And print them out #bigbrother1984

cd G:\Assign2\

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b "G:\Assign2\*.mp3"') DO echo %%G >> Found_MusicFiles.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b "G:\Assign2\*.JPG"') DO echo %%G >> Found_ImageFiles.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b "G:\Assign2\*.PNG"') DO echo %%G >> Found_ImageFiles.txt

 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b "G:\Assign2\*.exe"') DO echo %%G >>  Found_GamesFiles.txt
```

So for example this finds .mp3, jpg, png, exe files below Assign2, and prints out the results of what it finds.
But it prints them out like this
G:\Assign2\blah\blah\blah\blah\blah\Game.exe

I would like it to print out something like \blah\game.exe

Any ideas? I tried using %~nI, but I don't know how to use it and am new to batch.

Comment: You want the relative paths?

Comment: Or you want to use `%%~nG` in your for loops?

Comment: Your sample output starting with "C:\USers\..." does not match your script location, starting with "G:\Assign2\..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
@echo off
REM - Check to see if there are any non-school related files on the system (mp3, jpg, png, exe)
REM - And print them out #bigbrother1984

pushd "G:\Assign2\"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /a-d *.mp3 *.jpg *.png *.exe ') DO (
for %%b in ("%%~pa.") do >>"%userprofile%\desktop\Found_MusicFiles.txt" echo %%~nxb\%%~nxa
)
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you with some small modifications:

```
FOR %%a IN ("C:\USers\blah\blah\blah\blah\blah\Game.exe") do for %%b in ("%%~pa.") do echo \%%~nxb\%%~nxa
```

Comment: +1, Very nice. But I think the OP is misguided in wanting the leading \, as that implies an absolute folder starting at the root.

Answer (score 1):

Endoro has provided an answer that gives you exactly what you have asked for. But I suspect that may not really be what you want. You have asked for just the last folder in the path, but that may not be enough to tell where it is coming from.

I suspect you want the relative path, starting from your current directory.

The FORFILES command provides relative paths directly:

```
cd G:\Assign2
forfiles /s /m *.mp3 /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"
etc.
```

Or without needing CD

```
forfiles /s /p "G:\Assign2" /m *.mp3 /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"
etc.
```

The output would look like `".\blah\blah\file.mp3"`, where the `.` represents your starting location of `G:\Assign2`. (in other words, a relative path)

Comment: Endoro's code does nothing but print one static filename, with blah as the parent folder.  It's nowhere near 'exactly' what he asked for given the code supplied. :)  Endoro must have been very busy.  I think you're right though - the fellow probably wants more path info too.